# What could be wrong in the syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table where I am trying to put in foreign keys, and it gives me this error (`#1005 - Can't create table databasemodule.transactions (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)`):

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
    TsID INT NOT NULL,
    BookingDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    DepartureDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    Passenger INT NOT NULL,
    Flight INT NOT NULL,
    TYPE BLOB NOT NULL,
    Employee INT NOT NULL,
    Charges INT NOT NULL,
    Discount INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY(TsID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Charges) REFERENCES Charges(ChID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Employee) REFERENCES Employee(EmpID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Passenger) REFERENCES Passenger(PsID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Discount) REFERENCES Discounts(DsID) 
);
```

two other tables as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Charges(
    ChID INT NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Amount INT(255) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY(ChID)
);

CREATE TABLE Discounts(
    DsID INT NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Amount INT(255) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(DsID)
);
```

If I leave only one foreign key out of 4, it works perfectly. Working with InnoDb, UTF-8 on phpmyadmin

Comment: In order to format code, select it and press the `{}` button at the top of the window.

Comment: Which one do you leave out to get it to work? Probably a typo with that one

Comment: You can leave it out any of them, and it will work any You leave, that's strange

Comment: What if you name the constraints? `CONSTRAINT FK_CARGES FOREIGN KEY...` Etcetera

Comment: It worked! can You explain why it has to be named?

Comment: It doesn't need to be named. Please read the manual, google your error message without your particular strings & compose a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know why it worked really. According to the manual, if a name is omitted, a name is automatically assigned. My hypothesis was, since you are trying to create multiple foreign keys, it's trying to assign the same name for each (if true, smells like a bug).